# Movie or TV episode about a possessed doll that a boy puts in a doll house with a necklace on it to contain it

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, horror

Answered!!
It's called Shadow Zone Teacher ate my homework

A boy has a possessed doll. The doll makes the mom fall off a chair. The boy puts the doll in a doll house and put a necklace on the doll house to contain the doll. The doll gets out by tricking the sister to remove the necklace. Then the doll takes the sister to a cliff by the water.

The doll is a white female doll. Mom boy and sister are white. I saw it in mid to late 90s.
It may be a movie or tv episode.

I saw this in the mid '90s.

Comment: Is this a movie? Book? Something else? Also, in roughly which year did you see or read this, and when do think it might've been made?

Comment: It was a movie or episode from a show. It was in the mid 90s that i saw it

Comment: *Amityville: Dollhouse* has some matching bits with the dolls and the dollhouse making things happen in the house.

Comment: Nope. That's not it unfortunately

Comment: Were the dolls plastic? Ragdolls? Porcelain? Animatronics? Were the characters caucasian? Black? Middle Eastern? Do you remember any hair colors? Was the necklace gold? Silver? A simple rope loop? Was the cliff by an ocean? A lake? A river? A creek?

Comment: I was one doll. White. It was like a barbie doll size. The doll was female as well. The cliff was by a ocean i believe.

Comment: I remember the mother,  son, daughter where all white

Comment: The necklace i don't remember but it was used to contain the doll in a doll house.

Comment: I don't remember if it was a movie or a tv movie/ tv series episode. I apologize for not remembering more

Comment: What country did you watch this in?

Comment: I live in USA. I saw it in the 90s around mid 90s. Don't know when it was made

Comment: The new details that are coming up with the questions, can you [edit] them into your question?

Comment: I edited it. Thank you

Comment: Can confirm saw it in 96. So it was made before 96

Comment: Jesus Christ I found it. It's shadow zone : Teacher ate my homework. It was released in 1997

Comment: https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x8f9vr1

Comment: @Jordan - Well done. You should post the correct title as an answer, so you can earn some additional reputation from it (assuming you wish to continue using this site). If you do post this as an answer, please also mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark on the left side of the answer... although, when answering one of your own questions, you need to wait until the question is 48 hours old before the site will let you do that.

Comment: I will add title. Thank you

Comment: @Jordan - When I suggested that you post an answer, I meant by typing it into the 'Your Answer' field further down the page, so that it appears as an actual answer rather than an edit to your question. It's entirely up to you if you want to post an actual answer or not, but if you'd like to earn some more reputation, you might as well do so. If you don't, then another user likely will, and they'll earn the upvotes and increased rep that could've been yours.

Comment: I went ahead and added a boilerplate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just so it doesn't get lost in the comments, the querent identified the film as *[Shadow Zone: My Teacher Ate My Homework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Zone:_My_Teacher_Ate_My_Homework)*

[image: DVD cover of Shadow Zone: My Teacher Ate My Homework]

> A Grim Reaper appears in a spooky classroom, then tells a tale about a student named Jesse Hackett, who hates his teacher, Mrs. Fink, and is soon doomed to be trapped in the Shadow Zone. After all, to enter the Shadow Zone, one merely needs a touch of evil.
>
> Jesse Hackett finds a doll at a store resembling his teacher. Things start to take a turn for the worse when the doll comes to life. Jesse and his friends destroy the evil doll. Then Jesse Hackett and Mrs. Fink reconcile. Jesse never becomes an eternal guest at the Shadow Zone.
>
> The Grim Reaper tells the audience that he hopes to see them doomed, and that he will have a room waiting for them in the Shadow Zone. Then with a chilling laugh, he walks down the school's hall to the entrance and disappears.

### Trailer

Answer (score 0):

This might be [*Vacaciones de Terror*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacaciones_de_terror), aka *Vacations of Terror*, a 1989 Mexican horror film.

> They arrive at the vacation house. Paulina's family – her uncle Fernando, his pregnant wife Lorena, and their children Gaby, and twins Jaime and Pedro – try to spend the weekend at the house, even though all of them except for Paulina and Fernando feel the house is ugly and unnerving. After Julio arrives, some strange phenomena occur like eggs exploding, the electrical system suddenly improves, and Gaby has hallucinations and nightmares of the witch trial. Next day while the children play around the house, Gaby falls in a pit where the witch's belongings were hidden. There she finds and is drawn by a disturbing doll that she keeps as a new toy.
>
> During an argument with Gaby about her new doll, Lorena suffers pregnancy complications, forcing Fernando to take her to the closest hospital and leaving Paulina and Julio in charge of the children. Gaby then acts menacingly and strangely, claiming the doll talks to her and that it is somehow able to create paranormal phenomena, like hallucinations and object manipulations. As Fernando and Lorena are gone longer than expected, Paulina and Julio do their best to keep the children safe. However, the doll takes over Gaby's body and attacks both teenagers, exposing its true nature. Meanwhile at the hospital, Lorena warns her husband that their children are in danger and begs him to go rescue them.
>
> Julio tries to use the amulet against the doll, but he is trapped inside a mirror. Gaby, under the doll's influence, tries to kill her cousin and her own father. However, Paulina uses the amulet on the doll and throws it into a fireplace, which causes a fire and breaks Julio free, who helps one of the twins escape the house and narrowly escapes. Sometime later the house is put up for sale and while it is visited by an interested family, the family's eldest daughter finds the haunted doll intact, implying that what happened to Gaby and her family could be repeated.

### Trailer

### Alternate Trailer

There's the evil doll, and the amulet (necklace) used to contain it. [This review of the first two films](https://bandsaboutmovies.com/2023/04/02/vinegar-syndrome-blu-ray-release-vacation-of-terror-1-and-2-1989-1991/) mentions that playing with a toy car influences their father's actual car, which might tie into them being able to use the doll to affect the mother.

[Found on the Tip of my Tongue Subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/c4xse1/tomthorror_movie_evil_dollhouse/) as a result of walking through results from a search for `horror film dollhouse`.

Comment: It looks like a promising candidate when you read the Wikipedia page, but I looked through the film on Tubi TV last night, and couldn't find the specific scenes described in the question. Also looked through the sequel on YouTube, and no dice there either.

Comment: Nope once agian both are wrong unfortunately.

Comment: There is literally a scene with the boy putting the doll in a doll house and putting a necklace on the doll house to contain it. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Also the movie has a mother,  son and sister.

Comment: The doll was also female

Comment: Fount it     https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x8f9vr1

Comment: @Jordan: Care to post it as an answer? :)